# Logstash giving Exception when searching any keyword on UI

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Started logstash with config set as **embedded=true** for elasticsearch. Getting following exception:

```
NativeException: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [initial], No indices / shards to search on, requested indices are []
```

whenever tried to search any keyword on UI.

Currently we are trying to test with static log files(copied from some server), not ever growing log files.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: The error means that no elasticsearch index was found (logstash hasn't created one yet nor added any documents). It's probably a logstash problem, so you probably should change tags for the questions.

Comment: definitely looks like logstash problem, but that tag doesn't exist and hence not allowing me to add new one

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the reason was that I was using a grok filter using the same capture name twice for different patterns, e.g.

```
filter{
  grok {
    type => "foo"
    keep_empty_captures => true
    pattern => [
      "(?<bar>/file/path/a)",
      "(?<bar>/file/path/b)"
    ]
  }
}
```

I replaced the second `<bar>` with a `<qux>` and the error disappeared.